# Unidentified icon in Mac status bar

Tags: icons, malware, spyware

I have an unidentified icon that sometimes appears in my status bar (MacOS High Sierra). Graphic quality is low. It looks like a white "O" on an orange background, with an upward-pointing white arrow.

When I click on it, a low-quality grey dialog box pops up. Options are "Show sync progress", "Enable automatic syncing" (that is already selected with a tick), and "Exit. When I click on any of those options the dialog box and icon disappear.

Suspect it is malware or spyware due to low quality of the graphics. No luck with scanning for malware or with a reverse image search for the icon. Can anyone assist me to identify what this is and what, if anything, I need to do about it?

[image: screenshot of icon image]

Comment: Can you look through applications in Finder to see if you find and icon that matches?

Comment: Thanks DrZoo - yes I worked it out in the end. It was an application I'd installed ages ago but hadn't used. The real icon looked quite different to the one in the status bar so I was fooled. At least now I know there was nothing to worry about!